# Get current Drive folder id in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a Google Workspace Add-on which I have enabled in Google Drive. I would like to get the current folder ID when in Google Drive and no files are selected nor any document is opened. I can't find any method of getting the ID from the DriveApp class. The ID is in the URL, like https://drive.google.com/drive/.../folders/FOLDER_ID, but I can't reach it since `window` is not defined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing a lot of work around this API, and I am pretty sure you can't get what you want.

If it were possible, it would be included in the event passed via the `homepageTrigger`. Which it is not.

`DocumentApp` and other doc apps have a `getActiveDocument()` method. But there is no equivalent on DriveApp.